# Group on based on Case statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I have below case statement in my query.

```
  case when ID is null then case when netID is null then [text] 
   when netID is not null then 'UnAssigned' else ID End
    else ID  end grp
```

I want to group into 2 categories 1)all the records which are populated from [text] column.
2)remaning
Any Ideas?Can some one point me in right direction?

Comment: do you mean something like "GROUP BY CASE WHEN ID is null and NetID is null then 1 else 0 end"

Comment: ya tried that its not grouping properly..

Comment: Hi @user, i tried reformatting your example code, but it doesn't make sense.  you have 2 `case`, but only 1 `end`. Please add the other `end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it worked for me...after adding another case in my select and then grouping it in SSRS

```
   case when ID is null then case when netID is null then 1
  when netID is not null then 0 else 0 End
    else 0 end grp
```

Thanks

Comment: This might simplify it: CASE WHEN ID IS NULL AND NetID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END